# Omxplayer Stop "Have a nice day"

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have a C# code developed to stream a video file encoded to raw H264 and stream using UDP protocol when I receive that stream using omxplayer it played about 30s and then stopped and display 'have a nice day'. But I can receive that stream using ffplay and vlc player (in windows) without any problem.

Then i tried to stream using vlc player. And also i got same issue. Stream stopped and displayed 'have a nice day'.If any one can help me to figure this out, it is very grateful.

code used to receive stream in omxplayer

omxplayer udp://224.1.1.1:1234[image][image]

I have given a screen shot of omxplayer when receiving the stream. According to this the buffer size of the omxplayer becomes 0 after playing some time. I tried changing the url of the stream as given below.

omxplayer -s udp://224.1.1.1:1234?overrun_nonfatal=1

Then that problem was alright. But the stream was not smoothly running. Can you suggest any better solution for this problem.

Thank You!